# Find the commit number in git repository through changes string

Tags: git

```
git log -p | grep "BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140"
-BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140
+BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140
```

I know I have the changes including the String "BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140"
How do I know in which commit number I made these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log -G"BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140"
# or
git log -S"BUSINESS_VERSION=3.13.0.140"
```

Both should work in your case, but `-S` and `-G` [behave differently](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) in some cases.